# Дифференциация "not defined" от "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Как различить случаи, когда:

1. Переменная объявлена, но имеет значение **undefined**:

```js
const obj = undefined
console.log( typeof obj === 'undefined');  // true
console.log(obj);   // undefined
```

2. Переменная не объявлена:

```js
console.log( typeof obj === 'undefined');   // true
console.log(obj);   // Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

Наверное, можно ловить исключение, выполняя **obj === undefined**, и делать вывод на на основании этого. Но, наверняка, есть более простой способ?

Comment: нет, нельзя никак узнать была ли объявлена переменная или нет.

Comment: Хотя и смысла в этом, наверное, нет - если обратиться к обычной переменной, которая не объявлена, то получим ReferenceError на этапе компиляции, а не на этапе выполнения; а в случае с объектами всегда можно проверить наличие свойства.

Comment: не понял сообщения

Comment: @MaximSize JS  - то интерпретируемый язык, а не компилируемый. Вы увидите ошибку только лишь дойдя до неё

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что когда переменная не объявлена то она выкидывает `Error`, а если объявлена то никаких ошибок нет. А если есть `Error` то мы легко можем его поймать в `try catch` блоке и сделать необходимые действия. Ниже пример:

```js
try {
  notDefined;
  console.log('Defined with value undefined 1');
} catch {
  console.log('Is not defined 1');
}

const definedWithUndefinedValue = undefined;

try {
  definedWithUndefinedValue;
  console.log('Defined with value undefined 2');
} catch {
  console.log('Is not defined 2');
}
```

Comment: подтвердил предположение автора в предпоследнем предложении, но не ответил на вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Ну зато не надо делать `obj === undefined` :) Если честно, просто не сразу догнал, что именно автор предположил) Мне удалить ответ?